# Trying to use a datatable that is generated from a datagridview by user input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datatable, report

I am trying to send my datatable that has been filtered using user input to a report but reports can only accept datasets. The problem I have here is that I don't want to do it through SQL Server. I want to keep the information local. Is there anyway that I can send the datatable to the report, or am I SOL?

How I filtered the datagridveiw and converted it to a useable table:

```
    // If & Try block
    string filter = " (DateTime >= #" + startDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And DateTime <= #" + endDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And TagIndex =" + integerProdNum + " )";

    view.RowFilter = filter;

    passingDataToReport = view.ToTable();
```

obviously there are if and try blocks around these, but this is how I am trying to convert the datagridview that has been filtered back into a datatable.

Then in the report viewer I have the following code:

```
        DataSet Data = new DataSet("Data");
        reportData = DataSheet.getPassingDataToReport();
        reportData.TableName = "DateTimeValue";
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource source = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Data_DateTimeValue", reportData);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
        this.reportViewer1.DataBind();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

I've looked this up extensively and have found nothing of help. 
As an Aside; what is the directive that .DataBind() is associated with?

Comment: `DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet("Data");  myDataSet.Tables.Add(view.ToTable());`

Comment: Yes this would add the table to a dataset, but since the dataset is created at runtime it wouldn't show up in the report generator wizard. Therefore I cannot access it to generate the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to send the DataTable to a pdf writer and write that out using for and if loops. I found out that you cannot send a datatable that is created in run time to a report Viewer. Code below:

```
    public void ExportToPdfTableFULL(DataTable dt, string path)
    {
        Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);

        if (path.Equals(null) | path.Equals("")) { path = defaultFilename; }
        try
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + "_FULL.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        }
        catch (System.NotSupportedException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Path. The PDF was saved at " + defaultFilename);
            path = defaultFilename;

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + "_FULL.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Close Your PDF Viewer to Allow the " + "\nProgram to Overwrite or change the Filename");
        }

        document.Open();

        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Image PNG = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("EisenmannLogo.png");

            document.Add(PNG);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        Paragraph companyInfo = new Paragraph("\n" + companyName.Text + "-" + textBox4.Text + "\n" + phoneNumber.Text + " | " + textBox3.Text + "\n" + address.Text + "\n" + state.Text + ",  " + zipCode.Text + " " + textBox2.Text + "\n");
        document.Add(companyInfo);

        Paragraph TagName = new Paragraph("\n" +  description.Text + "\n" + "\n");

        document.Add(TagName);
        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Image Chart_Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(graphedTags[0] + "_chart.png");
            Chart_Image.ScalePercent(62f);

            document.Add(Chart_Image);
        }
        catch(Exception) { }
        Paragraph Disclaimer = new Paragraph("\n" + "*The data has been printed out at " + printOutInterval + " minute intervals to reduce PDF size.*" + "\n" + "\n");
        Disclaimer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        int counterToShorten = 0;
        for (int namesGraphed = 0; namesGraphed < graphedTags.Count; namesGraphed++)
        {
            Paragraph spacing = new Paragraph("\n" + "\n");

            document.Add(spacing);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count-1);
            BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, false);

            iTextSharp.text.Font fontSize = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, 8f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
            iTextSharp.text.Font fontSize1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
            iTextSharp.text.Font fontSize2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(graphedTags[namesGraphed], fontSize2));
            cell.Colspan = 3;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
            table.AddCell(cell);
            for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Columns[j].ToString(), fontSize1));
                cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                cell2.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(185, 185, 185);
                table.AddCell(cell2);
            }
            table.HeaderRows = 1;
            for (int p = 0; p < columnHeaders.Count; p++) { Console.WriteLine(columnHeaders[p]); }


                document.Add(Disclaimer);
                for (int i = 0; i < (dt.Rows.Count); i++)
                {
                    if (columnHeaders.Contains("Tagname"))
                    {
                        if (graphedTags[namesGraphed].Equals(dt.Rows[i]["Tagname"].ToString()))
                        {
                            counterToShorten++;
                            if (counterToShorten >=  printOutInterval)
                            {
                                for (int k = 1; k < (dt.Columns.Count); k++)
                                {

                                    if (!dt.Rows[i][k].Equals(null))
                                    {
                                        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString(), fontSize));
                                        cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                                        table.AddCell(cell3);
                                        counterToShorten = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (columnHeaders.Contains("TagIndex"))
                    {
                        if (graphedTags[namesGraphed].Equals(dt.Rows[i]["TagIndex"].ToString()))
                        {
                            counterToShorten++;
                            if (counterToShorten >=printOutInterval)
                            {
                                for (int k = 1; k < (dt.Columns.Count); k++)
                                {
                                    int mulitplier = 10 * i;
                                    if (!dt.Rows[i][k].Equals(null))
                                    {
                                        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString(), fontSize));
                                        cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                                        table.AddCell(cell3);
                                        counterToShorten = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


            document.Add(table);
        }
        document.Close();
```

Here is the writer I created.